# Using Quest Powershell to gather info and report

Tags: powershell, quest

I need some help writing a script as i am struggling to understand the logic.
I basically have a list of user ids that i need to check to see if they have two certain AD groups. If they have, these need to be outputted into a csv and highlighted.

Can anyone help to get me started? I need to use the Quest Powershell cmdlets

Here is the code

```
$textFileContents = Get-Content C:\temp\powershell\users.txt
$results = @()
foreach($username in $textFileContents){
$groups = get-qaduser $username |select -expand memberof 
if ($groups -match "grpuip1" -and $groups -match "group2"){
    echo $group
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this to begin :

```
"user1","user2" | foreach { 
    $groups = get-qaduser $_ |select -expand memberof 
    if ($groups -match "GROUP1" -and $groups -match "GROUP2"){
        echo $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is what ive done but it dont produce an output or give an error.

Comment: $textFileContents = Get-Content C:\temp\powershell\users.txt
    $results = @()
    foreach($username in $textFileContents){
    $groups = get-qaduser $username |select -expand memberof 
    if ($groups -match "group2" -and $groups -match "group1"){
        $username | select Identity,Name,LastName | export-csv c:\temp\powershell\users.csv
    }
}

Comment: Same results as before                             $textFileContents = Get-Content C:\temp\powershell\users.txt
    $results = @()
    foreach($username in $textFileContents){
    $groups = get-qaduser $username |select -expand memberof 
    if ($groups -match "group2" -and $groups -match "group1"){
        echo $groups | select Identity,Name,LastName | export-csv c:\temp\powershell\users.csv
    }
}

Comment: Still returns nothing.

Comment: please edit your question and put your complete code and an extract of users.txt

Comment: still need more details : name of the two groups you're searching + a ligne of users.txt thanks

Comment: two group names are Workstationadmin and Serveradmin. not allowed to show user ids but they are simply 6 characters long stored ina txt file.

Comment: try to decompose the problem. Does this work ? `get-qaduser <userlogin>` and this one `get-qaduser <userlogin> |select -expand memberof `

Comment: Yes <userlogin> |select -expand memberof works and shows all groups

Comment: to be sure : you have allready replace group1 and group2 with workstationadmin ans serveradmin havent you ?

Comment: could you share the output of $groups ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the cmdlet Get-QADMemberOf instead of Get-QADUser. There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but it's retrieving more information than you need.

Try this to start with:

```
$textFileContents = Get-Content C:\temp\powershell\users.txt

# Rather than initializing the array, and adding new elements, 
# just output each element of the loop to the pipeline, and
# assign the results of the whole pipeline to the variable.
# This is *much* faster than adding to an array    
$results = $textFileContents | ForEach-Object {
  $userGroups = Get-QADMemberOf $_
  if ($userGroups -contains "group1" -and $userGroups -contains "group2") {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"UserName" = $_; "Groups" = ($userGroups -join ",");}
  }
}

$results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content C:\Filename.txt
```